# Rspec not changing count on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to resolve an issue with my rspec test to create an object but the count doesn't seem to change whatever i try. I am sure i am missing something very basic here.

Here is my rspec:

```
 before do
    login_account_admin(user)
    @group = Factory(:group, :code => "GR_111", :description => "description for GR_111")
    Group.stub!(:find).and_return(@group)
  end

  describe "#create" do

    it "should create a new group object" do
      group_params = {:code => "NEW_GROUP", :description => "description for NEW_GROUP"}
      expect {
        post :create, :service_id => service, :cdb_group => group_params, :button => "save", :format => "js"
      }.to change(Group, :count).by(1)
    end

    it "should not create a new group object with invalid code format" do
      group_params = {:code => "invalid", :description => "description for invalid code name group"}
      expect {
        post :create, :service_id => service, :cdb_group => group_params, :button => "save", :format => "js"
      }.to_not change(Group, :count)
    end

  end
```

"code" parameter can only contain uppercase letters A to Z, 0-9 and _

Here is the controller method definition for #create

```
def create
@group = Group.new(params[:cdb_group])
respond_to do |format|
  if params[:button] == "cancel"
    format.js   { render "hide_new"}
  elsif @group.save
    format.js   {
      render 'show_new_group'
    }
    format.html { redirect_to(some_path(@service), :notice => 'Group was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  end
end
end
```

Here is the Group model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates_uniqueness_of :code
    validates_presence_of :code, :description
    validates_format_of :code, :without => /[^A-Z0-9_]/ , :message => 'can only contain uppercase letters A to Z, 0-9 and _'
end
```

Whenever i try to run the rspec test I  get the following errors:-

```
 1) GroupsController User As Account Admin goes to #create should create a new group object
 Failure/Error: expect {
   count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:51

 2) GroupsController User As Account Admin goes to #create should not create a new group object with invalid code format
 Failure/Error: expect {
   count should not have changed, but did change from 2 to 1
 # ./spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:58
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated?

Comment: Need more details.  What does the Group model look like. Does it have validations that are failing.  Are you sure your tests arent working correctly and your code is actually wrong, and the tests are pointing that out?

Comment: i bet you can resolve it on your own after reading this: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/ another tip, always implement the `else` part

Comment: Hi @cpjolicoeur: I have updated the questions above to indicate how does the Group model looks like. Yes, the code is actually correct as it has been successfully tested via browser and I dont run into any errors there.

The else part is implemented. For the sake of brevity, i have not included it above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever our tests give us unexpected trouble, it's important to take a step back and re-evaluate our approach.  Usually, this is an indication of some design problem, either with the code we're testing or with tests themselves.

While it sounds like using a truncation strategy has fixed this particular problem (see more on that below), i would suggest that there is more to learn from the situation.

Consider the two examples from your spec above.  The only difference between them comes down to whether the `code` parameter is valid or not.  I would argue that these examples are really testing the `Group` **model**, not the **controller**.

Now, if we're confident in our model test coverage, then we can take a different approach to the controller spec.  From the controller's perspective, the model is a *collaborator* and in general, we always want to **avoid** indirectly testing collaborators.  In this case, we can use a mock to simulate the behavior of the `Group` model and only test the controller behavior in isolation.

Something like this (please note the code below is incomplete and untested):

```
# spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb
describe "#create" do

  before do
    # use a Test Double instead of a real model
    @new_group = double(Group)
    @params = { :cdb_group => 'stub_cdb_group_param', :service_id => service }
    # using should_receive ensures the controller calls new correctly
    Group.should_receive(:new).with(@params[:cdb_group]).and_return(@new_group)
  end

  context "when cancelled responding to js" do
    it "renders hide_new" do
      post :create, @params.merge({:button => "cancel", :format => "js"})
      expect(response).to render_template('hide_new')
    end
  end

  context "with valid params" do
    before do
      @new_group.should_receive(:save).and_return(true)
    end

    context "responding to json"  # ...

    context "responding to html"  # ...

    context "responding to xml"   #...
  end

  context "with invalid params" do
    before do
      @new_group.should_receive(:save).and_return(false)
    end

    # ...
  end

end
```

While the above doesn't specifically address the problem with record counts you were having, i suspect the problem may go away once you isolate your test targets correctly.

If you choose to stick with database truncation, consider using it selectively as described [here](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/).

I hope at least some of that helps :).

Comment: That's some excellent feedback on the tests that have been written. Indeed, they were testing model and not the controllers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling with my spec_helper.rb  file. It turns out that i have to change my database cleaning strategy to truncation. Here is my spec_helper file, for reference (https://gist.github.com/aliibrahim/7152042)

I changed this line in my code and disable use of transactional_fixtures

```
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

and my database cleaning strategy is now:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
```

This gives a clear database before the start/end of every scenario. Hope this helps anyone!

Comment: This is the proper answer. Unless I set the `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` the `assert_difference` never passes.

Answer (score 0):

You should test...

1) `Group.create(group_params).should be_true` after `group_params = ...`

If this fails, the problem probably related to model or test environment.

2) `response.status.should == 302` after `post ...`

If this fails, the problem probably related to session (authentication / authorization).

3) `assigns(:group).should be_valid` after `post ...`

If this fails, the problem probably related to controller.

Comment: I tested all the the 3 scenarios above and didn't get failure in any one of them.

Comment: hmm... How about `expect{ Group.create(group_params) }.to change(Group, :count).by(1)`?

Comment: This one actually passes. 
I think it has to do something with my spec_helper.rb file? If i do the debug inside the code, the @group object created in the  before block (via Factory) does appear (by checking Group.all.inspect) but after the post :group ...  when i check Group.all.inspect only the second created object appears. So therefore, the count doesn't change by 1 and remains the same. Here is the link to my spec_helper.rb file (https://gist.github.com/aliibrahim/7152042). Any thoughts on that? Thanks for your time so far!

Comment: I have been able to resolve it. See my answer above.